# hive: fixed log structure and daily analysis

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

i'm new to hive. i have logs stored in folders by date: `logs/2016/02/15/log-xxx.json`. i want to do a daily analysis on logs from the last day. i wan't to run a hiveQL on last 2-3 folders (timezone difference). how to do it efficiently?

1. i cannot tell hive to automatically discover new logs and add them as new partitions, right?
2. do i have to create external table before each query and later delete it?
3. is there any way to tell hive to just run the query on specified folders without creating any table?

Answer (score 0):

You can create database with partitions based on date.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE user (
  userId BIGINT,
  type INT,
  level TINYINT,
  date String
)
PARTITIONED BY (date String)
```

Hive uses schema-on-read - that means  if you will add files later manually to HDFS it will automatically take them into account during SELECT statement execution. 
Just put them into proper location according to the date

BUT, one moment you should take into account:

> Because when external table is declared, default table path is
>   changed to specified location in hive metadata which contains in
>   metastore, but about partition, nothing is changed, so, we must
>   manually add those metadata.

```
ALTER TABLE user ADD PARTITION(date='2010-02-22');
```

Read more here: http://blog.zhengdong.me/2012/02/22/hive-external-table-with-partitions/

Author of that post also provides script to automate adding of partitions.

Comment: but the folder structure is fixed and read-only. i don't want to copy gigabytes before each analysis. can i add an arbitrary existing directory as a partition?

Comment: something like 
ALTER TABLE test ADD PARTITION (dt='2014-03-05')   location /user/admin/log/2014/3/5'
should work